# Is there a good model I can use to predict returns on marketing spend that accommodates for diminishing returns?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scipy, data-science

I have a marketing data set that I am using to predict returns based on spends. I am currently using a linear regression model. The issue is that the line only fits the data to a certain point, then returns on marketing spend start to diminish. Is there a model I could use to better predict this?

For context, I am writing a script that will attempt to predict the best amount of marketing spend on customer segments given a budget. It will predict spending on the segment with the largest return until those returns diminish and it makes sense to spend on the next segment. I have the logic worked out, but need the model for predictions still. With a linear regression model, it will just say the best option is to spend all the money on the segment with the highest initial returns, since the line won't change. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, you might want to post this question over on cross-validated. However, you might consider a model that is linear in parameters. There are several basis functions that you can use here but the simplest is quadratic: $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \beta_2 x^2$, where $x$ could be your expenditure variable.

Comment: @webelo please be advised that questions that are too broad/general here will sound exactly like that to Cross Validated, too. You are very welcome to suggest CV when appropriate, but please do not sodso light-heartedly